# Why am i stuck in a constant loop when using 'while True'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried writing 'y' and 'n', but i'm stuck in this constant loop. I don't understand why.

```py
while True:
try:
    answer = int(input("Continue? y/n: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Please write y or n.")
    continue
else:
    break
if answer == 'y': 
    print("Yes")
if answer == 'n':
    print("No")
```

Comment: `int(input("Continue? y/n: "))` this tries to convert whatever you input to an `int`. What do you think the integer versions of `"y"` and `"n"` are?

Comment: please fix the indentation

Comment: In short, remove the `int()`. Typically, it's used to convert the output of `input()` to an `int` so you can do some mathematical operation on it. Example: `int("1")` returns `1`. `int("y")` raises a `ValueError` since there is no numerical equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments - you want a character not an integer input. Converting any non digit to int will cause a ValueError and start over.

```
while True:
    answer = input("Continue? y/n: ").lower()
    if answer in ("y","n"):
        break
    print("Please write y or n.")

if answer == 'y': 
    print("Yes")
elif answer == 'n':
    print("No")
```

should do it.